# Retrieving youtube most_viewed url

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

How to apply filter in the youtube most_viewed video .

Like url for most_viewed videos is :
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed?v=2

i wanted to apply filters inside the above url   .
like how to search the videos by keywords inside the most_viewed category .

Request :Please don't refer Youtube Developer Guide

Comment: What's wrong with 'Youtube Developer Guide'?

Answer (score 1):

The only filter I know of is the **category** keyword.  For example, to filter most viewed "Games" videos, you would use :

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed_Games?v=2

The complete [categories list](http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat) is made available by Google.

**[EDIT :]**

The manual page statement makes it clear :

> In general, parameters that are used for filtering and ordering
>   results **are only supported for search requests**.

Here is the [full manual page](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#Standard_feeds)

Hope this helps !

Comment: @user1142861 You're welcome ! Glad you found the right answer :)